# How do I create a div with text and an image side by side using display: inline-block and make them responsive

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, css-selectors

so I created a div with an image and a text, and I want them to be side by side, and when the resolution changes to mobile I want it to be in the following order: image first and the text under the image.

I developed the code like this:

```
<body>
  <div class = "container">
    <img src = "" style = "border: 1px solid black" height = "200" width = "200" />
<h2> test </h2>
    <p> </p>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
    div.container {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    P {
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</body>
```

I want it to stay that way
[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0qEq.png)

Comment: What about flexbox? Don't want to use it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, you can still use `flex` to get this work done.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/m8q3v1x2/7/) to playaround.

```css
 div.container, h2 {
      display: inline-block;
   
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class = "container">
    <img src = "http://placekitten.com/301/301" style = "border: 1px solid black" height = "200" width = "200" />
<h2> test </h2>
    <p> </p>
  </div>


</body>
```